# Remix - Contract A doesn't work anymore when I deploy contract B

Tags: remix, ganache, bug

I recently had to deploy my second contract on the local Ganache Blockchain (Windows) using http://remix.ethereum.org/.

But every single time I deploy contract B after I deployed contract A, contract A doesn't work anymore. No returns - nothing.

I really need both of the contracts to communicate with them and between.

Anyone else had the same issue or knows how to solve the problem? Thanks

PS: I'm using some of the openzeppelin libraries and get them via. a remote connection using the command "remixd -s "*PATH*"

Code to reproduce:

> test2.sol

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.24;

contract test2 {
    uint value = 1338;

    function getSender() public view returns(uint) {
        return value;
    }

    function setValue(uint _value) public {
        value = _value;
    }
}
```

> test.sol

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.24;

contract test {
    uint value = 1337;

    function getSender() public view returns(uint) {
        return value;
    }

    function setValue(uint _value) public {
        value = _value;
    }
}
```

When I deploy testCoin.sol and then deploy test.sol I cant access any function the testCoin.sol contract provides. The console says "call to testCoin.balanceOf" - that's all. No return, no message - simply nothing.

Comment: can you provide some code?

Comment: added an example to reproduce